# module 'torchvision.models' has no attribute 'ViT_B_16_Weights'

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, vision-transformer

I am unable to import ViT_B_16 from torchvision.

I have the below code:

```
import torch
import torchvision

from torch import nn
from torchvision import transforms

pretrained_vit_weights = torchvision.models.ViT_B_16_Weights.DEFAULT 

pretrained_vit = torchvision.models.vit_B_16(weights=pretrained_vit_weights).to(device)
```

and the error is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
      1 # 1. Get pretrained weights for ViT-Base
----> 2 pretrained_vit_weights = torchvision.models.ViT_B_16_Weights.DEFAULT
      3 
      4 # 2. Setup a ViT model instance with pretrained weights
      5 pretrained_vit = torchvision.models.vit_B_16(weights=pretrained_vit_weights).to(device)

AttributeError: module 'torchvision.models' has no attribute 'ViT_B_16_Weights'

resolve the error of module 'torchvision.models' has no attribute 'ViT_B_16_Weights'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`torch.models`](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/models.html), the function to initialize a **ViT-B-16** architecture is not <strike>`vit_B_16`</strike> but [`vit_b_16`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models/generated/torchvision.models.vit_b_16.html), lowercase "b".

As [@simeonovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21767810/simeonovich) and [@Dr. Snoopy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/dr-snoopy) discussed in the comments, you have on the other hand [`ViT_B_16_Weights`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.vit_b_16.html#torchvision.models.ViT_B_16_Weights) (capital letters) referring to the weight *enum*, it refers to the different pretrained_weights: `IMAGENET1K_V1` (also `DEFAULT`), `IMAGENET1K_SWAG_E2E_V1`, and `IMAGENET1K_SWAG_LINEAR_V1`.

So in summary:

- [`torchvision.models.vit_b_16`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/vision_transformer.py#L621) (*function*): returns a [`VisionTransformer`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/vision_transformer.html);
- [`torchvision.models.ViT_B_16_Weights`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/vision_transformer.py#L351) (*enum*): is an enum of weights.

Comment: Not according to the documentation https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.vit_b_16.html#torchvision.models.ViT_B_16_Weights

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy That documentation refers to a class containing pretrained weights. The module constructor itself is lowercase.

Comment: Yeah that is very confusing, seems it is a nested class

Comment: Maybe you can provide the full name/path to use that class.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy *"seems it is a nested class"*, `torchvision.models.vit_b_16` is a function while `torchvision.models.ViT_B_16_Weights` is an enum.